# How to fix MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener in a fragment?

Tags: java, android-fragments, timepicker

i'm doing my school project in android since days ago, and I got  a problem today.  I did a menu with fragments and I need to put a TimePickerDialog inside a fragment and for me it's impossible, everytime when I press the button lo launch the Dialog the app crashes.

I try to put implements in the class of the TimePickerFragment but it doens't work, I need to bring the things in my main fragment, not in the Dialog.

Here is my main fragment, called "DespertarFragment":

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //TimePicker picker = getView().findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
        //picker.setIs24HourView(true);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_despertar, container, false);
        mTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        Button buttonTimePicker = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonTimePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Seleccionar");
            }
        });

        Button buttonCancelAlarm = view.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        buttonCancelAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelAlarm();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
//This is the function I'm trying to get the time
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        updateTimeText(c);
        startAlarm(c);
    }
```

And here is the TimePickerFragment class:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }



}
```

I expect the date shows in the texview but it crashes before the dialog opens.

Edit: I forgot to put the crash:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nando.goodnighthommie, PID: 9584
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nando.goodnighthommie.TimePickerFragment cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener
        at com.nando.goodnighthommie.TimePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(TimePickerFragment.java:23)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:330)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1308)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: You've to implement TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener!

Comment: But if implement, how can I change the text in the main fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) this` is causing the crash

To fix this you can use the following approaches

1 implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` in `TimePickerFragment`

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override 
    public onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
       // TODO : implement the functionality
    }
}
```

2. create an object and use it

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO : implement the functionality
        }
    }, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

}

Comment: Okay, thank you! Now works, but the time doesn't pass to my main fragment, if you see my code you'll realize I'm trying to change the text with the time selected in the dialog.

Comment: You need to pass a callback to timedialog through which you can listen to time